# Refresh icon for button

Tags: c#, image, button, icons

I need to find an image like the Refresh button in IE that I can use for a button.  The button will refresh the data on one of my forms.

Where can I find an image like this and how do I make it appear on the button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Google](http://www.google.ca/search?q=free%20refresh%20icon&hl=en&prmd=ivns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=gb4nTtiCNefk0QHQ1MHaCg&ved=0CBkQsAQ&biw=1366&bih=643) is your friend.

```
myButton.Image = new Bitmap(pathToImageFile);
```

Or just assign the image property through the property sheet in the Visual Studio IDE.

More possible icons [here](http://findicons.com/search/internet-explorer-refresh/3) (which are IE style... though you never specified what version of IE). And [here](http://findicons.com/search/ie9-refresh)!

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but where can I find a Refresh image?

Comment: There are tons in the link I provided (the Google text). Just right click on one and save the image. You should just be careful that they are not copyrighted first (especially if you are developing a commercial application).

Answer (score 12):

Refresh-button by using standard font "Wingdings 3" with symbol 80 or 81:

```
button1.Font = new Font("Wingdings 3", 20, FontStyle.Bold);
button1.Text = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(81); // or 80
button1.Width = 40;
button1.Height = 40;
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If you want to do this in the designer, you can set the Font to Wingdings 3, and then set the Text to 'Q'.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a image as well as refresh icon, here:

### [Ajax loading image generator](http://www.ajaxload.info/)

For the button, I think you may set the image properties of button
sample code like:

```
this.mybutton.Image = new Bitmap("refresh.jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

You may find Refresh symbol within standard Unicode Keyboard Symbols:
Reload, refresh ⟲ ⟳

Just copy paste it in Visual Studio to your button Content field.
There is not need to specify special code.

Answer (score 1):

Use this site:
http://modernuiicons.com/

Copy  tag and put it inside the  tag.

Example for refresh icon inside a button:

```
<button width="45" height="45"><Path Width="34.8333" Height="41.1667" Canvas.Left="20.5833" Canvas.Top="17.4167" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 38,20.5833C 42.9908,20.5833 47.4912,22.6825 50.6667,26.046L 50.6667,17.4167L 55.4166,22.1667L 55.4167,34.8333L 42.75,34.8333L 38,30.0833L 46.8512,30.0833C 44.6768,27.6539 41.517,26.125 38,26.125C 31.9785,26.125 27.0037,30.6068 26.2296,36.4167L 20.6543,36.4167C 21.4543,27.5397 28.9148,20.5833 38,20.5833 Z M 38,49.875C 44.0215,49.875 48.9963,45.3932 49.7703,39.5833L 55.3457,39.5833C 54.5457,48.4603 47.0852,55.4167 38,55.4167C 33.0092,55.4167 28.5088,53.3175 25.3333,49.954L 25.3333,58.5833L 20.5833,53.8333L 20.5833,41.1667L 33.25,41.1667L 38,45.9167L 29.1487,45.9167C 31.3231,48.3461 34.483,49.875 38,49.875 Z "/></button>
```

Don't forget to fix the width and height of the button to adjust the icon